# dpkg: error processing package <package>: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package python3-pip (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration

dpkg: error processing package python3-setuptools (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration

dpkg: error processing package python3-wheel (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration

Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-pip
 python3-setuptools
 python3-wheel

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried several solutions found but nothing helped. Also, it is happening with any software I try to install.

Comment: Why not just google this error? You'll get tons of answers.

Comment: I tried and i found nothing solve this :(

Comment: Try to remove or purge these packages and reinstall them

Comment: I'm new to ubuntu and don't know a lot commands @MichaelO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this answer from AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/170808.

Apply it to the packages that are in a bad state. In your case, `python3-pip`, `python3-setuptools`, and `python3-wheel`:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you're new to Ubuntu, you should try the desktop environment, if it's not already installed; otherwise, if you plan on using the command line a lot, you should start out with the basics rather than jumping into `apt-get` immediately. I learned some of my Unix skills from Codecademy a long time ago, maybe that could help.

Comment: In fact i'm trying pyspark code using the terminal and i got some errors so trying to find solutions for this errors i reached this place :/